# Windows APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0x14000 not functioning as intended, how do I get it to work?

Tags: c#, volume, playback

I have been developing a small software that lets you control various windows features like turning the volume up, volume down, volume mute, and playing/pausing. I have managed to get the software to control the volume but the playing and pausing does not work. I followed Microsoft's official page regarding this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-appcommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN but it's just not working whatever I try. Is there a specific thing that the play pause only controls? I have tried Media Player and VLC Media Player but its not playing or pausing.

```
namespace MediaController
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x0319;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0x26000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0x14000;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void VolumeUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessageW(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
        }

        private void VolumeDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessageW(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
        }

        private void MuteBtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessageW(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
        }
        private void PlayBtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SendMessageW(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I am fairly new to c# so any recommendations or guidance on improving my code would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Typo, you meant to type 0x140000 instead of 0x14000.  Still wrong, the command is 14 decimal, 0xE0000 in hex.  Favor doing it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34877625/17034) to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for that, changing it to the way the person did in the link you sent works and is much easier then previously.